# Thermal equilibrium with different states of two systems

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

I can’t seem to understand this part regarding the concept of temperature as mentioned in the book *Heat and Thermodynamics* by Zemansky. The text is as follows:

> A scientific understanding of the concept of temperature builds upon thermal equilibrium, established in the zeroth law of thermodynamics. Consider a system A in the state $X_1,Y_1$ in thermal equilibrium with another system B in the state $X_1',Y_1'$. If system A is removed and its state changed, there will be found a second state $X_2,Y_2$ that’s in thermal equilibrium with the original state $X_1',Y_1'$ of system B.

I’m stuck at this part and can’t figure out why the second state $X_2,Y_2$ would be in thermal equilibrium with the original state of B.

Comment: What edition, page of Zemansky is this on?

Comment: For the benefit of other contributors, the quote is from page 10 of the 7th edition of Heat and Thermodynamics, Zemansky & Dittman

Answer (score 2):

To put the quote in context (pp 7-10 of Zemansky), he states that it is applicable to systems of constant mass (a closed system) and composition, each requiring *only one pair* of independent coordinates for its description, such as pressure and volume for a gas.

In that context, let's break down the quote for the case of an ideal gas for a closed system (n=constant). The equation of state for an ideal gas for one mole of gas is

$$pV=RT$$

Now, the beginning of the quote:

> Consider a system A in the state $X_1,Y_1$ in thermal equilibrium with
> another system B in the state $X_1',Y_1'$.

If $X$ and $X'$ are the pressures of systems A and B and $Y$ and $Y'$ are the volumes of systems A and B, and the two system are in thermal equilibrium, $T_{A}=T_{B}$, then it follows for an ideal gas that the product of the pressure and volume of system A will equal the product of the pressure and volume of system B, i.e.,

$$X_{1}Y_{1}=X'_{1}Y'_1$$

> If system A is removed and its state changed, there will be found a
> second state $X_2,Y_2$ that’s in thermal equilibrium with the original
> state $X_1',Y_1'$ of system B.

For our ideal gas, if the state of system A changes to state 2 with a different pressure and volume it will still be in thermal equilibrium with the original state of system B as long as the product of the pressure and volume in the new state is the same as the original, or

$$X_{2}Y_{2}=X_{1}Y_{1}=X'_{1}Y'_{1}$$

Hope this helps.